# lim sup and lim inf in a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I have been given this exercise:

Find $\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n$ and $\liminf_{n \to \infty} a_n$ and all accumulation points $AP(a_n)$ for $a_n := (-1){n(n+1) \over 2} \sqrt[n]{1+{1 \over n}}$  $(n \in \mathbb{N})$

With my own calculations I came to the solution that $a_n \to -\infty$ for $n \to \infty$ and thus $AP(a_n) = \{\}$

However, the offical solution gives $AP(a_n) = \{-1,1\}$ as solution. I cannot find a mistake in my own calculation or a reason why there should be any accumulation points. IOs the official solution wrong or did I make a mistake?

Comment: That is because you mistook $(-1)^{n(n+1)/2}$ as $(-1)\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}2\right)$

Comment: [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9ak6znnuk6)

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!